# Access query to partition data and sum each partition?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query with the fields    `date` `hour` and `value`.
It looks something like this

```
    date       hour   value 
    xx/xx/xx     15     100
    xx/xx/xx     30     122
    xx/xx/xx     45      50
    ...         100     100
    ...         115      23
    ...         ...     ...
    ...         ...     ...
    ...        2400     400
    ...          15      23
```

Basically, `date` is the date, `hour` is the hour, and `value` is the value for that particular 15 minute interval.  What I have been trying to figure out is a way to take each hour (so 15, 30, 45, and 100) or (1015, 1030, 1045, 1100) [As you can see hours are military-esque 1:00pm is 1300 and midnight 2400], and sum their values together.  So i am looking to return something like this:

```
    xx/xx/xx    100     372
    xx/xx/xx    200     23 + (130 data) + (145 data) + (200 data)
```

And so on...
The table has on average around 100 days and they all start from 15 to 2400 incrementing by 15 with varying numbers for the value column.

I have thought about using a partition, group by, etc. with no real ideas how to tackle it. Essentially I have to take 4 rows (an hour), sum their values, spit out the date, hour, and summed value then repeat for every day.  I am not asking for code, just some help with what i should be using since this seems like a simple problem minus the key to solving it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by Hour/100 will almost get you there - subtract 1 from the hour will make 1 AM fall to 99, and get included in the grouping. This will give a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Table1.Dte, Int(([tme]-1)/100) AS Hr, Sum(Table1.Val) AS TotVal
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Dte, Int(([tme]-1)/100);
```

Comment: Flawless!  Kudos to you and Laurence!  Your code worked perfectly with no hiccups and all data aggregated accordingly with the correct hours. Thank you for your help and I will analyze your method to better understand for next time!

Comment: @Brian This doesn't provide the requested output. For hour `100` it returns `0`. How is that correct?

Comment: @ErikE, from this part of the question: *(so 15, 30, 45, and 100) or (1015, 1030, 1045, 1100)*

Comment: @Sean from this part of the question: *xx/xx/xx    200     23 + (130 data) + (145 data) + (200 data)* it's clear the 130 should round up to 200 and **display** `200`, not `1`

Answer (score 0):

I may have misremembered how you cast to int in Access, but this might work:

```
Select
  [date],
  100 * (1 + Cint(([Hour] - 1) / 100)),
  Sum(Value)
From
  Query
Group By
  [date],
  100 * (1 + Cint(([Hour] - 1) / 100))
Order By
  1, 2
```

Comment: This is beautiful! It seems to be adding 100, 115, 130, 145 as opposed to 115, 130, 145, 200, but I am not complaining and I should be able to fix that. Thank you so much for the speedy and spot on solution!

Comment: I was about to select yours for the answer, but I noticed the other two below, and Sean's fixed the timing addition, but thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   DateCol,
   Int(HourCol \ -100) * -100 AS Hr,
   Sum(Value) AS Value
FROM
   YourTable
GROUP BY
   DateCol,
   Int(HourCol \ -100) * -100
```

Or you can use `((Hr + 99) \ 100) * 100`.

Comment: Thank you! Your method also worked, but the hours were not displaying properly, a simple fix but I chose Sean's for the answer as his worked off the bat.  Thank you for your well written code and I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Sorry... I missed that you were rounding up, not down. I fixed it. This expression is the simplest answer given that returns the values you asked for.